# LruCache and Concurrent acces gridview / listview with BitMap from files in Android

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Before write this thread, I read a lot of stackoverflow thread, and also many tutorial.

I think people maybe some times write tutorial only to "write something".

I use a gridview to show file (imageView+textView) from files
I've got my File's list  called files. I set up a Custom BaseAdappter. It worked very well, because rather in a folder I' ve got more than 5 image. So in adapter I can call 3 different method from imageView: imageView.setImageResource(), setImageBitmpa(), setImageUri(). I used the last, because I can call Uri.fromFile(file) after get current file in adapter.

I found big problems when go to "DCIM/Camera" folder. Here, my apps work without crash. Scrool is really fast. This, because I follow all google developer instructions to manage bitmap. 
So, now my adater use AsynkTask and also a LruCache. The example by official google developer page use methods where bitma is decoded from resource. So I had to edit some line, and change decodeResource() in decodeFile();

this last method want fileName, and Options. So, my app show "well" all image from default gallery folder, but with a big problem.

After a totally load of gridview, if I scrool down 20 row (example), and return at position 0 scrolling up, many imageView are changed with other image. This problems happens all time I do a little or large scrool.

I cannot post any Log, any Error, because AS not show me any Error. Only some time Log show me something like "WaitForConcurrentGcToComlete blocked..."

Thanks

Comment: If you scroll down your views will be reused in `getView` of your base adapter. It looks like your getView also reuses your images if they are at different places when scrolling up and down. Just a suggestion without seeing your code.. ;)

Comment: I use view pattern hold in getView. I tried also to remove holder pattern and inizialize alla time my imageview, but with same result. Thanks for comment